# Tips and Tricks of WCF

Tags: wcf

After working with WCF with one of my asp.net web application , i really like the way that the ajax stuff works with my application...

Some useful Tips and Tricks about WCF from experts would be really helpful for beginners like me... Any useful tip and trick ....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm no expert, but there is plenty of information out there:

[Windows Communication Foundation Essentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee354181.aspx)

[WCF Guidelines and Best Practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731197.aspx)

[Best Practices for Security in WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731059.aspx)

[WCF Best Practices](http://mehranikoo.net/CS/archive/2008/05/31/WCF_5F00_Best_5F00_Practices.aspx)

[WCF Security Best Practices](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/WCF_Security_Best_Practices)

[WCF 3.5 Security Guidelines](http://www.codeplex.com/wikipage?ProjectName=WCFSecurity&title=Guidelines)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the excellent links that Mitch provided, I very strongly encourage you to get a copy of Juval Lowy's excellent "[Programming WCF Services - 2nd Edition](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596521301/)."  It is generally considered the "bible" of WCF and is one of my all time favorite technical books.

If you *really* want to **learn** WCF, you can't do a lot better than reading even just the first few chapters of this book.

[image]